# Make a int returning function behave as an lvalue and rvalue

Tags: c++, function, c++17

I hope I am technically accurate in formulating this query. While lvalues and rvalues are new to me as an in-depth topic, I could not help but draw similarities between how some functions tend to behave dually and how it relates to this. I assume lack of proper terminologies is causing my research into this topic futile, but I want to know how to approach implementation to the following two definitions of the same function `index_at`:

```
int number = matrix_.index_at(row_val, col_val)
matrix_.index_at(row_val, col_val) = 200;
```

Any references to help guide me in this regard are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's worth noting that this question has nothing to do with Rvalues. The `index_at(...) = ...` syntax would idiomatically be done using only Lvalues. Rvalues are a completely different thing used for efficiently stealing data from expiring objects. Really this is just about having a function that returns a mutable reference

Comment: "Any references" - you made a pun and didn't even know it!

Comment: @Human-Compiler precisely what I could not put a finger on. This does clarify it a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not definitions of functions; they seem to be invocations of member functions.

Are those two different functions? Not necessarily. If that member function is declared like so:

```
int& index_at(std::size_t row, std::size_t col);
```

then this same member function could be used on both lines. It is possible to define such functions! A classic example is the [`std::vector::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) function (or rather its non-const variant): It is implemented essentially (*) as:

```
T& at(std::size_t pos) { return *(this->data() + pos); }
```

where `data()` returns a pointer to the first element in the allocated space for the `std::vector`.

`std::vector::at()` is also an example of how your two member function invocations could be of *different* members:

I hope this answers your question.

---

<sub>(*) Plus bounds checking, which I am ignoring here.</sub>

Comment: Note that the actual `vector::at` will also do bounds checking, but that just gets in the way of making the point.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I did say "essentially"... see edit.

Comment: @einpoklum `vector::operator[]` might have been a better example to choose from

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, but I didn't want to confuse OP with operator overloading.